# New matrix operation. Does it have a name? Is it useful?

Tags: probability, matrices, group-theory

Matrix multiplication can be defined as:

$$({\bf A}{\bf B})_{kl} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} {\bf A}_{ki}{\bf B}_{il}$$

Lately, I have been thinking of another operation:

$$({\bf A} \vec{\circ} {\bf B})_{kl} = \prod_{i=1}^{n} {{\bf A}_{ki}}^{{\bf B}_{il}}$$

The ordinary one can be viewed as a linear weighting. The second one can be viewed as a geometric weighting. If working on non-negative reals this could for instance be used calculating probabilities. If we work with $\bf A$ over the complex numbers this is useful at least for averaging on a circle as can be done in [my answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352523/how-to-find-the-shift-that-minimizes-the-difference-between-two-vectors/1352527?noredirect=1#comment2749926_1352527). Also

$$\log({\bf A} \vec{\circ} {\bf A}^T)_{kl} = \sum_{i=1}^n {\bf A}_{ki} \log({\bf A}_{ki})$$
Which is the Shannon information entropy with reversed sign.

Does anyone know if this operation has a specific name? Can it be used for other things as well?

Comment: One should avoid denoting this operation by ${\bf A} \otimes {\bf B}$, which is the standard notation for the Kronecker product of two matrices. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Comment: Yes sorry, I am actually aware of this. Will try and find some better un-used symbol.

Comment: What is $n$ in the indices?

Comment: It is the size of the dimension. So that one full row of $\bf A$ and one full column of $\bf B$ is involved in each result. Nice trick by the way.